# Converting a BlobBuilder to string, in HTML5 Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, html, blob

```
          function blobToString(blob) {
             var reader = new FileReader();
             var d = "";
             reader.onloadend = function() {
                 d.callback(reader.result); 
                 console.log(reader.result);
             };
             reader.readAsText(blob);  
             return d;
         };
```

The above code does not work, but I guess my intentions are clear, I want to convert some binary data(WebKitBlobBuilder) to a string. Also the "console.log(reader.result);" doesn't display anything.

Comment: How are you calling `blobToString`?

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://blog.ericzhang.com/state-of-binary-in-the-browser/ and [his binary.js project](http://binaryjs.com/).

Comment: These links as answers are rarely useful. This one especially isn't - too much text to read on that page. Which section is applicable?

Answer (score 0):

it should not be  reader.onloadend but rather  reader.onloaded

or try

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
e.target.result -> this is the data. 
}
```